# Geometry question - Prove that $S_{AMD}<S_{MBN}$

Tags: geometry

For square $ABCD$, equilateral triangle $MDN$. Prove that $S_{\Delta AMD}<S_{\Delta MBN}$

[image]

---

My try: $\Delta AMD=\Delta DNC$

$\Rightarrow AM=DN\Rightarrow MB=NB$

Have: $S_{\Delta AMD}:\frac{AM\cdot AD}{2};S_{\Delta DNC}:\frac{MB\cdot NB}{2}=\frac{MB^2}{2}$

Need prove $\frac{AM\cdot AD}{2}<\frac{MB^2}{2}$

..... And i just need prove $AM=\frac{1}{3}\cdot AB$, or help me another way

Comment: $S_{AMD}=S_{MBN}$ or $S_{AMD}<S_{MBN}$? The title and the content do not match.

Comment: i edited it sorry

Comment: `equilateral triangle MDN` Think you meant $\triangle M\color{red}{C}N$ there.

Comment: this is wrong picture, i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ *EDIT* ]  Changed $\,C \mapsto D\,$ to match OP's updated figure.

Hint:  assume WLOG that $AB=1\,$, and let $AM=x$. For $\triangle DMN$ to be equilateral:

$$
DM^2=1+x^2 = (1-x)^2+(1-x)^2 = MN^2 \;\;\implies\;\; x = 2 - \sqrt{3}
$$

Then $S_{AMD}=\frac{1}{2} x\,$ and $S_{MBN}=\frac{1}{2}(1-x)^2\,$, so the problem reduces to verifying the inequality.

Comment: why $CM^2=1+x^2 = (1-x)^2+(1-x)^2 = MN^2 \Rightarrow  x = 2 - \sqrt{3}$

Comment: @WordShallow $C=MN$ because $\triangle MCN$ is equilateral. Then $CM^2=CA^2+AM^2$ and $MN^2=BM^2+BN^2$ by Pythagoras' theorem in the respective right triangles. Finally, $1+x^2 = 2(1-x)^2$ is a quadratic equation with the only root within $(0,1)$ equal to $2-\sqrt{3}\,$.

Comment: @WordShallow P.S. Replace $C \mapsto D$ in my previous comment to match your updated figure.